# Improper Cache Management in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

The joomla 2.5.22 site allows user to go back to the browsed pages even after a
successful log out. I tried the following steps:
1. Open the page after login authentication
2. Browsed some pages and logout from the website
3. Click on Workoffline option in Firefox
4. Open the pages from the browser Cache and still some authenticated pages are opened

Is there any way to delete the browser history on logout ? 
This is a security issue. how can we overcome from it? Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use Firefox's Incognito window.

Answer (score 2):

```
3. Click on Workoffline option in Firefox
```

It is a function of Firefox - working offline.

You can add HTTP headers, so that the page is not cached, look there for examples:

[How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)